# Facebook SDK, Login Error

Tags: objective-c, facebook, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I'm setting up my app so that users can login with Facebook. I've loaded the Facebook SDK, but for some reason I get this error in the console when I try to "log in" to Facebook:

**FBSDKLog: Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x10906da90 {com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=, expirationDate: 2014-01-02 03:26:48 +0000, refreshDate: 2013-11-03 06:19:26 +0000, attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions.**

Does anyone know why? Take a look at the code below. I feel like it has something to do with my ShowLoginView method (I'm attempting to open the SSLoginViewcontroller Xib on top of an existing Storyboard). I was able to log into Facebook fine before I started messing with this method... Help :)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
 self.mainViewController = [[SSViewController alloc]
                           initWithNibName:@"SSViewController" bundle:nil];
self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                      initWithRootViewController:self.mainViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


    if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
        // Yes, so just open the session (this won't display any UX).
        [self openSession];
    } else {
        // No, display the login page.
        [self showLoginView];

    }
        return YES;

}

- (void)showLoginView
{


    UIViewController *topViewController = [self.navController topViewController];
    UIViewController *modalViewController = [topViewController modalViewController];

    // If the login screen is not already displayed, display it. If the login screen is
    // displayed, then getting back here means the login in progress did not successfully
    // complete. In that case, notify the login view so it can update its UI appropriately.
    if (![modalViewController isKindOfClass:[SSLoginViewController class]]) {
        SSLoginViewController* loginViewController = [[SSLoginViewController alloc]
                                                      initWithNibName:@"SSLoginViewController"
                                                      bundle:nil];
        [topViewController presentViewController:loginViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    } else {
        SSLoginViewController* loginViewController =
        (SSLoginViewController*)modalViewController;
        [loginViewController loginFailed];
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you alloc & init'ing SSLoginViewController *twice*??

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Didn't even notice that; just removed one lol. Now the console is saying 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <UITabBarController: 0x10930a400>.' What would be an alternative way (code) to present the modal view on top of my storyboard? Thank you! :) See code edit above.

Comment: Which "`presentModalViewController`" line (you have two in that function) is that error coming from and why?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I'm assuming the first one, as the app shuts down as soon as I hit "run". I've been feeling like that first line has been throwing it off to begin with [self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:self.mainViewController animated:NO]; I'm just not sure what to replace it with? Taking it out stops the app from crashing, but it completely stops my "LogOut" method from working.

Comment: I don't know why you're even doing the "`UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard...`" thing you're doing.  I don't do that in my own code. Why not just go straight to the "`if (FBSession.activeSession.state...`" line in your first function and see if it works?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Woah, you're right. It works without it. Nice one, lol. Okay, but now my Logout button doesn't work (I can see it, but clicking on it doesn't clear my session)? See edits above.